# Let A,B,C be some bounded intervals in R the set of real Number.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A,B,C be some bounded intervals in R the set of real Number. Suppose A contains C and B contains C. Does this imply C is contained in intersection of A and B.

I think this is true because if $A=(0,1$) $B=(1/4,1)$  and $C=(1/2,1)$ then A intersection B is (1/4,1) and this contains C which is $(1/2,1)$
But I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: **Hint :** "$A$ contains $C$" means that "$C$ is contained in $A$". And to prove that a set is contained in another set, you just have to pick an element of the first one, and to prove that it also belongs to the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the fact that $A, B, C$ are real intervals. This is true for any sets. If $C \subseteq A, C \subseteq B$ then $ C \subseteq A \cap B$.

Proof is quite simple. Take $c \in C$, by hypothesis $c \in A$ and $c \in B$. So $c \in A \cap B$ by definition of the intersection.

In general to prove that a set $R$ is included in another one $S$, you just have to prove that for any $r \in R$, $r$ also belongs to $S$.